# Resuming from hibernation Color profile Error

Tags: suspend, hibernate, xps, xserver

When resuming from hibernation I get the following error message:

> Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.

Followed by only an <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

Then nothing happens, and the x server isn't starting. I then have to reboot the computer, and everything works as usual - but my hibernate session is lost. This is not every time I resume but happens about once a week.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: What where you expecting?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Well - that X-server starts up as usual. It just hangs at the above message. I then have to reboot and it works like usual, but my hibernate-session is lost.